# configure: error: libopenvswitch.a was not found. Try --with-ovs-libpath

Tags: sdn, openvswitch

When i use this command:

```
./configure --with-ovs-srcdir=/home/mx/SDN/openvswitch-2.10.1 PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

I had got the error result:

```
configure: error: libopenvswitch.a was not found. Try --with-ovs-libpath
```

But in my computer, i can find libopenvswitch.a file:

```
/lib/libopenvswitch.a 
/usr/local/lib/libopenvswitch.a
/home/mx/SDN/openvswitch-2.10.1/lib/.libs/libopenvswitch.a
```

But i use the command:

```
./configure --with-ovs-srcdir=/home/mx/SDN/openvswitch-2.10.1 --with-ovs-libpath=/lib/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

or command:

```
./configure --with-ovs-srcdir=/home/mx/SDN/openvswitch-2.10.1 --with-ovs-libpath=/usr/local/lib/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

or command:

```
./configure --with-ovs-srcdir=/home/mx/SDN/openvswitch-2.10.1 --with-ovs-libpath=/home/mx/SDN/openvswitch-2.10.1/lib/.libs/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
```

all get same error result:

```
configure: error: libopenvswitch.a was not found. Try --with-ovs-libpath
```

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What software do you want to build? How did you install Open vSwitch?

Comment: thanks. I want to build of-config. I install Open vSwitch by follows step: 1. download the openvswitch-2.10.1.tar.gz      2. tar -xf openvswitch-2.10.1.tar.gz     3. use this command:  ./configure --prefix=/ --datarootdir=/usr/local/share --with-linux=/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build     4.make && make install

Comment: thanks. I want to build of-config. I install Open vSwitch by follows step: 1. download the openvswitch-2.10.1.tar.gz      2. tar -xf openvswitch-2.10.1.tar.gz     3. use this command:  ./configure --prefix=/ --datarootdir=/usr/local/share --with-linux=/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build     4.make && make install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **version 2.3.1 of Open vSwitch** to build OF-CONFIG.

---

I can reproduce your issue if I try to install OF-CONFIG with the last version of Open vSwitch:

```
$ ./configure --with-ovs-srcdir=/ovs PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
...
configure: error: libopenvswitch.a was not found. Try --with-ovs-libpath
```

If I install Open vSwitch 2.3.1, however, everything works as expected:

```
$ wget http://openvswitch.org/releases/openvswitch-2.3.1.tar.gz
$ tar -xf openvswitch-2.3.1.tar.gz
$ cd openvswitch-2.3.1/
$ ./configure --prefix=/ --datarootdir=/usr/share
...
$ make -j && sudo make install -j
...

$ cd /of-config
$ ./configure --with-ovs-srcdir=/openvswitch-2.3.1 PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/
...
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Thank you very much!   The Ubuntu 16.04 can install the Open vSwitch 2.3.1 or not?  or must use Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: When i install Open vSwitch 2.3.1 in Ubuntu 16.04, I get this error:configure: error: Linux kernel in /lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/build is version 4.13.13, but version newer than 3.14.x is not supported (please refer to the FAQ for advice)

Comment: When i install Open vSwitch 2.3.1 in Ubuntu 16.04, I get this error:configure: error: Linux kernel in /lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/build is version 4.13.13, but version newer than 3.14.x is not supported (please refer to the FAQ for advice)

Comment: Thank you very very much！ I had install the of-config, thanks!

Comment: If you want OVS with the Linux datapath, you will need to downgrade your kernel.

Comment: Thanks， I install the Open vSwitch and OF-Config successful. But when i run ofc-server, i get this message:ofc-server[45085]: OpenFlow: could not connect to 'ofc-bridge' bridge.

Comment: That looks like a different problem. Maybe one of the components did not start correctly... Could you accept this answer if it solves the original problem and open a second question with details for the new issue?